# Call operator (&) runs command in new window when omitting ".cmd" if a file with the same name exists in the same directory

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, node-modules, powershell-core

If I omit the suffix ".cmd" in a command, it gets opened in a new window. Why is this? What triggers the new window to open?

In **Powershell 5** and **Powershell Core 7**, the first of the following causes a new window to open, while the other three show the outputs in the same window:

1. `& 'C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava' 'help'`
2. `& '.\node_modules\.bin\ava' 'help'` (used `cd C:\some_path` before)
3. `& 'C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava.cmd' 'help'`
4. `& 'C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava.ps1' 'help'`

Meanwhile in **cmd** all three programs show their output in the same window, no new window gets opened at all:

1. `C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava help`
2. `.\node_modules\.bin\ava help` (used `cd C:\some_path` before)
3. `C:\some_path\.bin\ava help`

---

I used the help command only as example, finally I like to use `ava debug --serial someFile.js`

---

SW-Versions:

- Windows: Windows 10, Version 2004 (Build 19041.388)
- Node: v12.18.3
- AVA: 3.11.0

---

There are three relevant files located in the `.bin` directory:

`ava.cmd`

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\..\ava\cli.js" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

`ava.ps1`

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
$basedir=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

$exe=""
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt "6.0" -or $IsWindows) {
  # Fix case when both the Windows and Linux builds of Node
  # are installed in the same directory
  $exe=".exe"
}
$ret=0
if (Test-Path "$basedir/node$exe") {
  & "$basedir/node$exe"  "$basedir/../ava/cli.js" $args
  $ret=$LASTEXITCODE
} else {
  & "node$exe"  "$basedir/../ava/cli.js" $args
  $ret=$LASTEXITCODE
}
exit $ret
```

`ava`

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../ava/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../ava/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

---

Since the call is done by visual studio code debugging an AVA script with the [proposed configuration](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/bc39bcc3ff92cb2979564ec2e69dc72be6509f78/docs/recipes/debugging-with-vscode.md), my influence on the used commands is limited.

---

`$env:PATHEXT` equals `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL`

---

If I rename the file `ava` to `ava_2`, no new window gets opened anymore. If a create an empty file named `ava`, the command `& 'C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava' 'help'` opens a new window again.

Comment: What if you try `Get-Help` instead of `help` ?

Comment: Using `Get-Help` instead of `help` does not help for two reasons: 1. I used the help command only as example, finally I like to use `ava debug --serial someFile.js` 2. `Get-Help` states in its own help: "Displays help about PowerShell cmdlets and concepts."

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening.  Is node.exe set to run js files, and is .JS taken out of $env:pathext ?  I think that would cause it, similar to trying to run .py files without adding .PY to PATHEXT.

Comment: With a fully-qualified path (i.e. no search), it executes the filename without an extension. Without an extension, it calls `ShellExecuteExW` instead of `CreateProcessW`.  `ShellExecuteExW` does not use `PATHEXT`, but it does have a default list of file extensions that it tries, which includes ".CMD". The default behavior of `ShellExecuteExW` is to create a new console window unless passed the flag `SEE_MASK_NO_CONSOLE`. The second case, which is relative to the working directory ("."), is implemented like a search and thus resolves to "ava.ps1", which is executed by the current shell process.

Comment: @ErykSun looks like adding a folder to the PATH makes it like the second case.

Comment: @ErykSun Your comment looks more like an answer. Would you mind adding it as an answer? Besides: How did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Start-Process instead, so you can control whether it opens a new window or not?

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\some_path\node_modules\.bin\ava' -ArgumentList 'help' -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Since the call is done by visual studio code debugging an AVA script with the [proposed configuration](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/bc39bcc3ff92cb2979564ec2e69dc72be6509f78/docs/recipes/debugging-with-vscode.md), my influence on the used commands is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Add .cmd to pathext would fix it if it were missing.  Ava is a package for [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) javascript runtime.

```
$env:PATHEXT += ';.CMD'
C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\.bin\ava.cmd help
```

Adding it to the path would fix it:

```
$env:path += ';C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\.bin'
ava help
```

This same folder that has ava.cmd, has a file named ava that's a shell script, and a file named ava.ps1 that's a powershell script.  For some reason hiding or renaming the "ava" shell script fixes it as well.

Referring to the current directory also works:

```
.\Windows\System32\node_modules\.bin\ava help
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
'' | set-content hi
'echo cmd:hi' | set-content hi.cmd
& $pwd\hi  # pops open another window for a split second
```

Comment: `$env:PATHEXT` equals `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL` already.

Since we install AVA in every project as local npm package, I am not going to add every `.bin` directory to `$env:path`

Answer (score 0):

That is decided by the PATHEXT Variable...

See [MS Learn - The PATH Command and PATHEXT Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc723564(v=technet.10)#the-path-command-and-pathext-variable)

On my Windows 10 machine the order is set to...

```
$env:PATHEXT -split ';'

.COM
.EXE
.BAT
.CMD
.VBS
.VBE
.JS
.JSE
.WSF
.WSH
.MSC
.CPL
```